# Cygwin User/home folder non existant

Tags: directory, root, cygwin, home-directory

I'm a novice at cygwin/linux administration so please be patient with my ignorance:

I'm trying to change my .bashrc profile and setup (.gitconfig ) I can't seem to find my home folder.

My hypothesis is that i don't have my home folder because i've remapped  my dos $HOME path. Could this be the trick?

Anyways how would one rebuild the home folder ? Uninstall and reinstall cygwin? (i'd like to avoid this if possible).

Thanks a plethora in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up a cygwin shell instead of a cmd shell you should start out in your home directory. `cygpath` and `pwd` should be able to help you figure out where you are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $HOME is set when Cygwin is invoked, Cygwin will use that as your home directory. Otherwise it reads the location of your home directory from /etc/passwd.

Comment: Could i change the .bat file of the cygwin to avoid this? if so how would i do it?

Comment: Yes, add `set HOME=` to cygwin.bat to unset that variable.